# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (285, 30) instead

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, svm

I am using this data set below and I am trying to find the support vector machine of the data set. Also
I have my code and error below as well.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html#sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer
[image]

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm,datasets
breastcancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
#print(breastcancer)
everydata = breastcancer.data
#print(everydata)
everytarget = breastcancer.target
traindata = []
traintarget = []
testdata = []
testclasses = []
#Class 0 data separtion
for i in range(0,140):
    traindata.append(everydata[i])
    traintarget.append(everytarget[i])
for i in range(140,212):
    testdata.append(everydata[i])
#Class 1 data separation
for i in range(212,357):
    traindata.append(everydata[i])
    traintarget.append(everytarget[i])
for i in range(357,569):
    testdata.append(everydata[i])
traindata = np.concatenate((everydata[:140, :],everydata[212:357, :]),axis=0)
traintarget = np.concatenate((everydata[:140],everydata[212:357]),axis=0)
testdata = np.concatenate((everydata[140:212, :],everydata[357:569, :]),axis=0)
print(len(traindata))
print(traintarget)
print(testdata)
dd = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
dd.fit(traindata,traintarget)
decide = dd.predict(testdata)
print(decide)
```

Why am I getting this error is my concatenation incorrect. The results are supposed to output 0s and 1s at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `everydaydata` to build the `traintarget` dataset, but you should use the labels in `everytarget`. That is why is complaining abut the shape, because the labels should be one dimensional.

Try replacing this:

```
traintarget = np.concatenate((everydata[:140],everydata[212:357]),axis=0)
```

with this:

```
traintarget = np.concatenate((everytarget[:140],everytarget[212:357]),axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

So the error is risen on your `dd.fit(traindata,traintarget)` lane.
If you print your `traintarget.shape()`, you'll see it's `(285, 30)`. Target (often called y_train) is the array that should have only outputs of your training set, so the model can learn links between X_train (traindata) and y_train.

Here your y_train have 30 attributes, where it should be 1 (just the 1 or 0 target you're looking at) as your error mentions you.

In fact, in your traintarget (y_train), you have to isolate the column from the 30 of traindata (X_train) that represents the target you want to train the model for.

To fit your model, you then need : Your traindata EXCLUDING the target (similar to the data you'll have to predict), and your traintarget with ONLY the target corresponding to your traindata.